# Excel - how to select the largest values that account for 60% of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have 6 rows of data with a cost:

[image]

I would like to select the top data entries whose cost account for e.g. 60% of my total cost. Here, the formula would flag Bananas, Lemons and Oranges since it is the selection that covers at least 60% of the total.

I need to select the largest values first.

In substance, I would like to find a function that does the same as
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$12, MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$12, D3), $B$2:$B$12, 0))`

Any clue?

[link to file](https://quantisintl-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/simon_vankerckhove_quantis-intl_com/EY_EH12rWVlFhcqDusyCfwUBpRejO48QuGu6WWLrdtbiDg?e=l1WzqA)
In this file, the first column represents the cost, the second is the cumulative sum and the last is the percentage of data covered.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. How you advise me to rework this question?

Comment: As far as I can see none of them account for 60%. Lemons and bananas are 4 of 15 which is about 25% only.

Comment: Visual representations are great, but a table of your data rather than a picture of it would help anyone who wanted to test an answer. Are you trying to select all the items until you reach 60% of 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B7,2,-1),SEQUENCE(MATCH(TRUE,((MMULT(--(SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B2:B7))<=SEQUENCE(COUNT(B2:B7))),SORT(B2:B7,,-1))/B8)*100)>=60,0)),{1;2})
```

Where `MMULT(--(SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B2:B7))<=SEQUENCE(COUNT(B2:B7))),B2:B7)` is used to create a running total array.